# how to take an integer and use a fraction on it

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def main():
    name=input("Enter your name: ") #just write our name nothin important
    print (name, "is Swag")
    value1=int(input("enter a value: ")) #takes in the number without doubt
    print(value1)
    value2=float(int("Enter a fraction: ")) #heres our problem but what?
    print(value2)
main()
```

just a simple program I am playing about with but It shows this error since you all might want to know:

I write for example 1/2 an this shows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\waliu\Documents\Waliur Uni stuff\Information 
systems\Python Programs\Samples\apparently fractions.py", line 8, in 
<module>
main()
File "C:\Users\waliu\Documents\Waliur Uni stuff\Information 
systems\Python Programs\Samples\apparently fractions.py", line 6, in main
value2=float(input("Enter a fraction: "))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1/2'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a `fractions` module in the standard library. It can parse a string containing a representation of a fraction.

```
from fractions import Fraction

s = input("Enter a fraction: ")
val = Fraction(s)
print(val, float(val))
```

**demo**

```
Enter a fraction: 3/8
3/8 0.375
```

Note that the string can't contain internal spaces, but it can have spaces before or after the data.

---

If you want to do calculations with fractions it's a good idea to *not* convert them to floats, since that loses precision. And since Fraction objects use Python integers for the numerator & denominator there's no limit to how accurate they can be (apart from RAM limitations). Here's a short demo:

```
a = Fraction('2/3')
b = Fraction(3, 4)
c = a**2 + b**2
print(c)
print(c**10)
```

**output**

```
145/144
4108469075197275390625/3833759992447475122176
```

Answer (score 2):

python won't evaluate fractions, unless you're using `eval` (which is unsafe so I cannot recommend it). There are other expression evaluators like `simpleeval`, but in your case, if you're sure that a fraction is entered you could just split, convert to integer and divide:

```
>>> fraction = "1 / 2"  # input("enter a fraction")
>>> f = [int(x) for x in fraction.split("/")]
>>> f[0]/f[1]
0.5
>>>
```

you could handle non-fractions by just checking `len(f)==2`, otherwise it's either a simple integer (if `len(f)==1`), or an error (if > 2).

one-liner using `operator.truediv` & passing the args directly:

```
operator.truediv(*(int(x) for x in fraction.split("/")))
```

(no syntax check possible here obviously)

Comment: forgot about that one. Good. I'm beginning to think that could be a duplicate. and it is, in some way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806278/convert-fraction-to-float

Comment: Thanks yall for the helpouts