# How to convert a string containing "/" to a float in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-conversion

I have some dimensions typed as a text in inches format, example:
text = "20 7/8 16 1/4" # the first two represent, let's say, the length, and the second two represent the width
I can change this string into a list of strings using text.split() to get: ["20", "7/8", "16", "1/4"].

Now, I want to add the first two items 20 + 7/8 to get 20.875. How can I convert 7/8 to a float number?

Comment: Since you're using python3, you can use [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval): `map(eval, ["20", "7/8", "16", "1/4"])`

Comment: @pault I really just hate seeing `eval` anywhere :/

Comment: @roganjosh I know but it kind of works nicely here. Caveat for OP: [Why is eval bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)?

Comment: @pault I guess it kinds works in a lot of places until... it works too well :P

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> from __future__ import division
... 
... result = []
... text = "20 7/8 16 1/4"
... for num in text.split():
...     try:
...         numerator, denominator = (int(a) for a in num.split('/'))
...         result.append(numerator / denominator)
...     except ValueError:
...         result.append(int(num))
... 
>>> result
[20, 0.875, 16, 0.25]
```

Comment: Don't need `from __future__ import division` for python3

Comment: @pault You are correct. I just have a Python 2.7 project open in PyCharm so that is what console I'm currently using. Sometimes I also like using `operator.truediv` for Python 2/3 compatibility since it's very obvious.

Answer (score 5):

[A quick Google search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806278/convert-fraction-to-float) can show you the answer

```
from fractions import Fraction
print float(Fraction('7/8'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
text = "7/8"
x = text.find("/")
numerator = float(text[0:x])
denominator = float(text[x+1:])
print(numerator/denominator)
```

Comment: Your answer was flagged as low quality because it lacks explanation.  Expand upon why your answer works, or it will be deleted.

Comment: The code is self-explaining .. take the number to the left of " / ", convert it to a float, take the number to the right of " / ", convert it to a float; then perform a normal division !!

Answer (score 0):

> How can I convert 7/8 to a float number?

```
a="7/8".split("/")
a=int(a[0])/int(a[1])
```

Or if you don't care about safety:

```
a=eval("7/8")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num = '7/8'.split('/')
dec = int(num[0]) / int(num[1])
```

Comment: Yes, it would work.