# Convert String of Backtick (`) + fraction to Float

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with an excel file which I read into python as a pandas dataframe.
One of the columns contains responses of how many hours a person slept.
A sample column is as follows:

```
df['Sleep'] = [1, 2, 3, 'Blank', 4, 'Blank', '5`1/2', '`3/4']
```

My objective is to clean this data and get it all into a single datatype with NaN for Blanks. The blanks were taken care of using:

```
df['Sleep'] = df.['Sleep'].replace('Blank',np.nan)
```

My question is how can I convert something like 5`1/2 to 5.5? All fractions in the dataset start with the backtick symbol.

Comment: Similar, but not the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806278/convert-fraction-to-float

Answer (score 2):

We have to use `loc` with `fillna` (because you have mixed types) and `pd.eval`

```
m = df['Sleep'].str.contains('`', na=False)
df.loc[m, 'Sleep'] = df.loc[m, 'Sleep'].str.replace('`', '+').apply(pd.eval)
df['Sleep'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Sleep'], errors='coerce')

   Sleep
0      1
1      2
2      3
3  Blank
4      4
5  Blank
6    5.5
7   0.75
```

Comment: This works however the resulting value is still a string. Is there a way to have it be returned and saved as float? Or do I have to loop through and convert?

Comment: @aalhendi - add `df['Sleep'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Sleep'], errors='coerce')`

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
df[df['Sleep'].str.contains("`")] = eval(df['Sleep'].str.replace("`","+"))
```

Comment: Did you run this? It will not work, not sure how it got 2 upvotes

Answer (score 1):

```
def convert_to_float(frac_str):
    try:
        return float(frac_str)
    except ValueError:
        num, denom = frac_str.split('/')
        try:
            leading, num = num.split('`')
            whole = float(leading)
        except ValueError:
            whole = 0
        frac = float(num) / float(denom)
        return whole - frac if whole < 0 else whole + frac

 df["Sleep"] = df["Sleep"].apply(lambda x: convert_to_float(x))
```