# Convert fractional values to decimal in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, operators

I have a dataframe with messy data.

```
df:
    1        2        3
--  -------  -------  -------
 0  123/100  221/100  103/50
 1  49/100   333/100  223/50
 2  153/100  81/50    229/100
 3  183/100  47/25    31/20
 4  2.23     3.2      3.04
 5  2.39     3.61     2.69
```

I want the fractional values to be converted to decimal with the conversion formula being

e.g:

- 123/100 = (123/100 + 1) = 2.23
- 333/100 = (333/100 +1) = 4.33

The calculation is `fractional value + 1`

And of course leave the decimal values as is.

How can I do it in Pandas and Python?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1806309/7128934

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do this is to first define a conversion function that will be applied to each element in a column:

```
def convert(s):
    if '/' in s: # is a fraction
        num, den = s.split('/')
        return 1+(int(num)/int(den))
    else:
        return float(s)
```

Then use the `.apply` function to run all elements of a column through this function:

```
df['1'] = df['1'].apply(convert)
```

Result:

```
df['1']:

0    2.23
1    1.49
2    2.53
3    2.83
4    2.23
5    2.39
```

Then repeat on any other column as needed.

Comment: Use `applymap` on the whole dataframe ;)

Comment: `df.applymap(lambda x: [1 + a/b for a, b in [[int(a) for a in x.split('/')]]][0] if "/" in x else float(x))`

Answer (score 1):

If you trust the data in your dataset, the simplest way is to use `eval` or better, suggested by @mozway, [`pd.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html):

```
>>> df.replace(r'(\d+)/(\d+)', r'1+\1/\2', regex=True).applymap(pd.eval)
      1     2     3
0  2.23  3.21  3.06
1  1.49  4.33  5.46
2  2.53  2.62  3.29
3  2.83  2.88  2.55
4  2.23  3.20  3.04
5  2.39  3.61  2.69
```

Comment: Use `pd.eval`, it is safe