# python script to convert mixed fraction to float

Tags: python

I have 2 columns in a table, say,

column 1-feild_fraction(type: data or string) to enter fraction values like 1/2, 1-1/2, 3/2, 3-1/2 and

Column 2-feild_decimal(type: float), when i enter fraction data in column one, i need float values to be displayed as 0.5, 1.5, 1.5, 3.5

Any solutions?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806278/convert-fraction-to-float

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert fraction to float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806278/convert-fraction-to-float)