# Why are floating point types invalid template parameter types for template functions?

Tags: c++, floating-point, template-function

I read on a website that the declaration

```
template <int x>
int func() {
  return x;
}
```

is valid while the following is not

```
template <double x>
double func() {
  return x;
}
```

Why is the first a legal declaration for a template function while the second is not?

Comment: A link to the website would be helpful.

Comment: Its just an mcq where there were 3 options out of which these were first two,third one was a template declaration involving typename and had to pick up invalid one and the answer is one with double..

Comment: I think it basically comes down to it being difficult to specify what floating point equality means in a way that can work reasonably well across different compilers and floating point representations.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183087/c-why-cant-i-use-float-value-as-a-template-parameter

Comment: BTW: If you are looking for a way around this restriction.  Create a class that has an inline static method that returns the value you want, and pass the class as the template parameter instead.

Comment: Your question is [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11518757/241631) in the question linked by @VaughnCato.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not valid because it is not an integral type. There are certain restrictions on nontype template parameters and this is one of them, which says ...

> Floating-point numbers and class-type objects are not allowed as nontype template parameters.

```
template <double VAT>       // ERROR: floating-point values are not
double process(double v) { // allowed as template parameters
    return v * VAT;
}

template <std::string name> // ERROR: class-type objects are not
class MyClass {             // allowed as template parameters
  /* ... */
};
```

The above is quoted from [C++ Templates](http://books.google.com/books?id=yQU-NlmQb_UC&pg=PA40&lpg=PA40&dq=4.3%20Restrictions%20for%20Nontype%20Template%20Parameters&source=bl&ots=EelI25_yE1&sig=3J2keL-N8V9QLAplWem0gLdKAvw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=uLAcUNfHKKyujAKU3IGABA&ved=0CEsQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=4.3%20Restrictions%20for%20Nontype%20Template%20Parameters&f=false). I take no credits for it.

The reason why they are not valid for template initialization, as per my understanding, is because types like float and double don't have a defined implementation in C++. So when a template like

```
template <double VAT> double process(double v);
```

is initialized with two different double values as

```
template <(double) 2/3> double process(2.3)

template <(double) 1/3> double process(2.4);
```

they might not have same bit representation because of double nontype, which confuses the compiler.

Comment: The question is *why* floating point types are not valid non-type template parameters.

Comment: @Prætorian- Added the reason, as per my understanding. Please correct if wrong.