# C++ template with float arguments

Tags: c++, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++: Why can’t I use float value as a template parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183087/c-why-cant-i-use-float-value-as-a-template-parameter)

I have this class:

```
template<typename ValueType, ValueType DefaultValue>
class SomeClass
{
    public:
        SomeClass() : m_value(DefaultValue){}

        ValueType m_value;
};
```

I want to use it like this:

```
SomeClass<int, 1> intObj; //ok
SomeClass<float, 1.f> floatObj; //error: 'float' : illegal type for non-type template parameter 'DefaultValue'
```

Can you please explain me why I get this error when using `float`?

I want to use something similar to represent RGBA colors and to initialize the channels with default value for different color representations(White for example).

Comment: The short answer is simply that the standard doesn't allow it.

Comment: @K-ballo yes, it's the same question. Please close:)

Comment: @Felics: I've already voted to close it, waiting for 4 more votes...

Comment: @K-ballo I already voted:) +3

Comment: That duplicate is very handy as to the why, as well as a workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The language does not allow the use of floating-point types as non-type template arguments. For an extensive discussion, see [Why can't I use float value as a template parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183087/c-why-cant-i-use-float-value-as-a-template-parameter)

Answer (score 3):

§ 14.1/7 (C++11 N3485) explicitly forbids this:

> A non-type template-parameter shall not be declared to have ﬂoating point, class, or void type. [ Example:

```
template<double d> class X; // error  
template<double* pd> class Y; // OK  
template<double& rd> class Z; // OK
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ doesn't support floating-point non-type template parameters unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because *non-type template parameters* cannot be of type `float`. They may only be *integrals*, *enumerations*, *member-pointers* or *addresses*.

Answer (score 0):

That's simple: nontype template parameters have to be compiletime constants of integral type or pointer type, i.e. bool, enums, pointers, pointer-to-members, long, int, short, char. Floating point parameters are not allowed in the current standard.

Comment: They can be _enumerations_ as well.

Comment: added that just at the time you posted your comment ;)