# How to convert a struct into a template parameter pack?

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns

Ok suppose I have a `struct` like so:

```
struct Example{
  uint8_t var0;
  uint32_t var1;
  uint16_t var2;
};
```

And suppose I have an instance (note constexpr) of the class that looks like this:

```
constexpr Example exp = {10,11,12};
```

And I want to somehow get the bit representation of this into a template parameter pack.

An example of what this would look like:

```
typedef SomeTemplate<
        /* first variable: 1 byte */   10,
        /* second variable: 4 bytes */ 11, 0, 0, 0,
        /* third variable: 2 bytes */  12, 0> mydef;
```

My knee jerk response to doing this is to do some template meta programming magic with some unions, but unfortunately this is not possible because accessing a union in the way I want is undefined behavior at compile time (ie error).

My ultimate goal with all of this is to put an instance of a user defined type into as a template parameter....something like this:

```
template<Example exp>
class OtherClass{
};
```

So the reason I am on this rabbit trail is I could take class Example and give a templated constructor which would take a list of `uint8_t`s in and then initialize itself that way (thus still `constexpr` and effectively allowing me to pass it in directly).

So is there any way to convert an arbitrary struct instance into an bit pattern at compile time (and all `constexpr`)?

Comment: Any concerns in using something like [ffi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface) instead?

Comment: @user430051 I don't understand how that would help......could you enlighten me?

Comment: template <Example (*f)(exp)>, where *f is a pointer to a function.

Comment: @user430051 Actually I have experimented a little with that

Comment: @DarthRubik maybe this will be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15896579/why-cant-a-struct-be-passed-as-value-as-template-non-type-parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I eventually ended up doing:

```
template<class T,class... Args_t>
struct Statifier{
    constexpr T operator()() { return T(Args_t()...); }
    constexpr operator T() { return T(Args_t()...); }
};
```

And then you use it like so:

```
template<class T, T value>
using ic = integral_constant<T,value>;
struct Point{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    constexpr Point(int x,int y,int z) : x(x),y(y),z(z) { }
};
typedef Statifier<Point,ic<int,12>,ic<int,12>,ic<int,12> > triple;
```

`triple` is now a type and can be passed into a template parameter.

Limits of this approach:

- You can only use types which can be differentiated by their constructors
- You have to use types that have `constexpr` constructors
- It can be cumbersome to initialize

But it is still awesome.

Thanks for you comments....they did help me find this method