# Why template nontype parameter pointer and reference arguments needs to be global

Tags: c++, templates, global, local, non-type

Why arguments which are passed as nontype arguments should be global and not local? Isn't both created and allocated memory during compile time only?

In this case p is a const pointer, so it cannot point to any other variable then also its giving error.Why?

```
template<int* ptr>
class A{};

int x;
int *const p = &x;

int main() {
    x = 9;
    A<&x> ob;
    A<p> ob2;//giving error
    cin.get();
}
```

Also why only integral type is allowed as nontype parameters, not char or float?

Comment: Also, please _show_ the errors you get, all of them and without editing. Then it will be easier to say exactly what's wrong.

Comment: Error: template parameter 'ptr' : 'p' : an expression involving objects with internal linkage cannot be used as a non-type argument

Comment: Template arguments need to be known during compilation. Addresses of global variables are fixed offsets, known to the compiler. Address of a local, OTOH, depends on the call stack - the compiler doesn't know how will it look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concerning the first question, I am not a compiler expert, but I can guess it makes the compiler's life easier, and perhaps it is a limitation that comes from older versions of C++, where `constexpr` was not available.

Nevertheless, paragraph 14.3.2/1 of the C++11 Standard is quite clear as to what is allowed and what is not:

> A template-argument for a non-type, non-template template-parameter shall be one of:
>
> — for a non-type template-parameter of integral or enumeration type, a converted constant expression
>   (5.19) of the type of the template-parameter; or
>
> — the name of a non-type template-parameter; or
>
> — **a constant expression (5.19) that designates the address of an object with static storage duration and
>   external or internal linkage** or a function with external or internal linkage, including function templates
>   and function template-ids but excluding non-static class members, **expressed (ignoring parentheses) as
>   & id-expression**, except that the & may be omitted if the name refers to a function or array and shall
>   be omitted if the corresponding template-parameter is a reference; or
>
> — a constant expression that evaluates to a null pointer value (4.10); or
>
> — a constant expression that evaluates to a null member pointer value (4.11); or
>
> — a pointer to member expressed as described in 5.3.1; or
>
> — an address constant expression of type std::nullptr_t.

Concerning your second question, instead, a `char` *is* allowed. For instance, the following is a legal program:

```
template<char c>
struct X
{
    // ...
};

int main()
{
    X<'c'> x;
}
```

Concerning the reasons why floating point types are not allowed, you can find some information in [this Q&A on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693994/understanding-of-non-type-template-parameters/16694256#16694256).

Comment: I checked the link provided by you, one thing I didnt understand is when compiler performs equality comparisons it will perform it on data types and not on values, so why it is difficult.

Comment: @Gaurav: No, it will perform it on values - that's the whole point of having non-type parameters: you are providing values as arguments instead of types.

Comment: Correct me if I am getting it wrong. For eg if I do A<2.3> ob and A<5.67> ob2 so it might generate two different instances of class A.

Comment: @Gaurav: `A<2.3>` and `A<5.67>` are two different instances of class template `A`. `ob` is an instance of class `A<2.3>` and `ob2` is an instance of class `A<5.67>`.

Comment: So you are telling that compiler will generate two different class A for float values. A for 2.3 and A for 5.6. so ob and ob2 will not be instance of same type of class.If i do it for int, like A<5> ob1 and A<10> ob2 then?

Comment: @Gaurav: Yes, `A<2.3>` and `A<5.6>` are different classes, so `ob1` and `ob2` are not instances of the same class. Same for `A<5>` and `A<10>`: they are different classes, and `ob1` and `ob2` are not instances of the same class.

Comment: when its same for int also, then why dont they allow float as nontype parameter

Comment: @Gaurav: It is explained in the linked Q&A. `A<5 * 2>` and `A<10>` are the same class, but (just as an example, don't take it literally) `A<0.1>` and `A<0.2 / 2>` may not be, because of floating point imprecision

Comment: Sorry for bothering you so much. One last thing about that const pointer p in my code. Will you please give some idea on that.

Comment: @Gaurav: I thought I covered that in my answer :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30502/discussion-between-gaurav-and-andy-prowl)

Comment: @Gaurav: I don't have time for that now, sorry :(