# A "hack" to get float template parameter working compiles but segfaulted on both g++ and clang

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, reinterpret-cast

I know [why I can't use float as template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183087/why-cant-i-use-float-value-as-a-template-parameter) and how to set a static const float member of template class thanks to a *numerator/denominator* couple. But I was trying another "hack" based on reinterpret_cast to "emule" float template parameters from its **IEEE754** hexadecimal writing.

Here is the small piece of code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

template <uint32_t T>
struct MyStruct
{
    static const float value;
};

template <uint32_t T>
const float MyStruct<T>::value = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(T);

int main()
{
    typedef MyStruct<0x40490fdb> Test;
    std::cout << Test::value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it...

```
g++ -Wall -pedantic main.cpp -std=c++0x -g
```

with no warnings.

And it segfaulted...

```
brugelca@artemis:~/workspace/draft$ ./a.out 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Here is the valgrind output :

```
brugelca@artemis:~/workspace/draft$ valgrind ./a.out
==10871== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==10871== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==10871== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==10871== Command: ./a.out
==10871== 
==10871== Invalid read of size 4
==10871==    at 0x4008B5: __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) (main.cpp:11)
==10871==    by 0x4008D1: _GLOBAL__sub_I_main (main.cpp:18)
==10871==    by 0x40093C: __libc_csu_init (in /home/brugelca/workspace/draft/a.out)
==10871==    by 0x5159D74: (below main) (libc-start.c:219)
==10871==  Address 0x40490fdb is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==10871== 
==10871== 
==10871== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==10871==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x40490FDB
==10871==    at 0x4008B5: __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) (main.cpp:11)
==10871==    by 0x4008D1: _GLOBAL__sub_I_main (main.cpp:18)
==10871==    by 0x40093C: __libc_csu_init (in /home/brugelca/workspace/draft/a.out)
==10871==    by 0x5159D74: (below main) (libc-start.c:219)
==10871==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==10871==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==10871==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==10871==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==10871==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==10871== 
==10871== HEAP SUMMARY:
==10871==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10871==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==10871== 
==10871== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==10871== 
==10871== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==10871== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

Should this code compile ? (I was a bit surprised that both clang and g++ allow the reinterpret_cast) Why does it segfaulted ? How to achieve what I wanted in the first place ?

Comment: What in the world.. is that a random hex address?

Comment: You should guess. ;-)

Comment: May I add that *no warnings* has never meant *no segfaults*. Compilers are brilliant, but they cannot anticipate **all** human mistakes : there are far too many of them.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: The answer is as easy as pi.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code reinterprets `0x40490fdb` as a pointer to `float`, not as the hex value of a `float`. Hence the segfault.

Try the following:

```
constexpr float uint32_to_float(uint32_t val) {
  return *reinterpret_cast<float*>(&val);
}

template <uint32_t T>
const float MyStruct<T>::value = uint32_to_float(T);
```

Comment: @matovitch: See the updated answer with a proposed workaround.

Comment: I think I  will delete this question. First because I am ashamed of it and second because I don't think this will be useful to anyone else.

Comment: And without constexpr (I think it's c++11) ?

Comment: @matovitch: You are of course free to delete any of your questions. Doing so is, however, disrespectful towards those who have made the effort to try and help you.

Comment: You lose the reputation points you gained ? Anyway since you edited your answer this could be useful to someone so I will keep it.

Comment: @matovitch: It's not about the points, but about respecting each other's time. BTW, the community does a pretty good job of swiftly closing unsuitable questions, and so far not a single close vote has been cast.

Comment: @NPE The advices my parents gave me have already vanished but your answer will stay. Am I being disrespectful ? The web has to settle for a little mortality.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames Unfortunately, not all floats could be represented in such way (ratio of integer numbers, even `int64_t` numbers).

Comment: @NPE (bis) My last comment looks bitter afterwards (which wasn't its spirit at all :-)). I just would say for example that the advices you gave orally disappeared but aren't necessary a waste of time. And the fact there wasn't a clerk to record all your words doesn't make the listening less respectful IMHO.

Comment: A slight improvement to this would be to cut down on the amount of asterisks by using the reference version of `reinterpret_cast` as such: `reinterpret_cast<float&>(val)`

Answer (score 1):

The segfault in the question was a vulgar mistake but the question remains. How to pass a float in ieee754 format as a template argument ?

### The C++11 way

This solution was given by *NPE* (modified but not tested) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

template <uint32_t T>
struct MyStruct
{
    static const float value;
}; 

constexpr float uint32_to_float(uint32_t val) {
    return reinterpret_cast<float&>(val);
}

template <uint32_t T>
const float MyStruct<T>::value = uint32_to_float(T);

int main()
{
    const uint32_t pi = 0x40490fdb;
    std::cout << MyStruct<pi>::value << std::endl;
}
```

### The old fashioned way

Relativly small, I'm proud of it ! :-)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

template <uint32_t T>
union MyStruct
{
    static const uint32_t int_val = T;
    static const float    flt_val;
};

template <uint32_t T>
const float MyStruct<T>::flt_val = reinterpret_cast<const float&>(MyStruct<T>::int_val);

int main()
{
    const uint32_t pi = 0x40490fdb;
    std::cout << MyStruct<pi>::flt_val << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```