# Can derived object cast to base reference in c++ template class?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, reference, polymorphism

all. I am trying to learn something about template inherit. I want to cast a temp derived object to its base reference. But I come across this problem:

```
typedef long size64_t;
//////Base class
template <typename _Scalar>
class MatrixBase{
public:
    virtual _Scalar operator()(size64_t rowid, size64_t colid) = 0;
};
//////Derived class 1
template <typename _Scalar>
class MatrixHolder : public MatrixBase<_Scalar>{
public:
    MatrixHolder(){};
    inline _Scalar  operator()(size64_t rowid, size64_t colid){return 0;}
};

//////Derived class 2
template <typename _Scalar>
class Matrix : public MatrixBase<_Scalar>{
public:
    Matrix(){};
    inline _Scalar  operator()(size64_t rowid, size64_t colid){return 0;}
};
//////The function with parameters as Base class reference, wanting to get derived object as input.
template <typename _Scalar>
MatrixHolder<_Scalar> apply(MatrixBase<_Scalar>& lhs, MatrixBase<_Scalar>& rhs){
    MatrixHolder<_Scalar> result;
    return result;
}
```

and in main, we have:

```
void main(){
    Matrix<double> m1;
    Matrix<double> m2;
    apply(m1, m2);//Sucess
    apply(m1, apply(m1, m2));//Fail
}

the compiler said:

note: candidate function [with _Scalar = double] not viable: no known conversion from
      'MatrixHolder<double>' to 'MatrixBase<double> &' for 2nd argument
MatrixHolder<_Scalar> apply(MatrixBase<_Scalar>& lhs, MatrixBase<_Scalar>& rhs){
                      ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: I think your problem is to use double as the template argument. 
As shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183087/why-cant-i-use-float-value-as-a-template-parameter to seems not to be possible

Comment: You're trying to bind a non-const reference to a temporary object. Make the parameters to `apply` const references.

Comment: @molbdnilo do you mean that all the temp object should be const?

Comment: @maple No, the function's parameters should be; `const MatrixBase<_Scalar>& rhs`. (This has nothing to do with either templates or inheritance, by the way.)

Comment: @StefanReinhardt Using the *type* double as a template parameter is not a problem. The problem you linked to is using floating-point *values* as template parameters.

Comment: @molbdnilo Ahh sry my fault of course you're right i was too fast with my conclusion because I got almost the same error when trying to use that a few days ago...

Comment: Side note: Do not `typedef long size64_t`, just use `std::size_t`

Comment: @DieterLücking Can you tell me that in detail? Is there some links talking about this?

Comment: @maple `std::size_t'` covers the maximum size possible. `long` might be shorter than 64 bits

Comment: @DieterLücking Thanks, it's really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
apply(m1, apply(m1, m2));//Fail
```

The problem here is that the inner `apply` returns a temporary, which cannot bind to the non-const reference parameter of the outer `apply`.

If you can make the parameters `MatrixBase<_Scalar> const&` it would be a possible match.