# Create alias for numeric array

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I want to create an alias of `std::array` with only numeric types

```
template<typename T, std::size_t n, T = std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>
using NumericArray = std::array<T, n>;
```

this works correctly with an integer

```
NumericArray<int, 2> i{1, 2};
```

But if I want a float or double I have an error due to the non-type template parameter

```
NumericArray<float, 2> f{1.0f, 2.0f};
```

There is some other way to do this?

Answer (score 10):

If you want to prevent someone form using this alias with non-arithmetic types, then you did it wrong.

Your code will allow any type that is a valid template argument and can be constructed from `bool` and that's all.

The proper solution would be something like this:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t n>
using NumericArray = std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, std::array<T, n>>;
```

---

**Why your code doesn't work:**

Look at this part:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t n, T = std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

It creates an unnamed template argument of type T and sets a default value for it.

Even if `std::is_arithmetic<T>::value` is false, the code will compile as long as `T` can be constructed from `bool`.

Of course, `T` must be also usable as a template argument. (That's why `float` does not work. Floating-point types can't be template arguments. See this: [Why can't I use float value as a template parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183087/why-cant-i-use-float-value-as-a-template-parameter))

Again, there is just no reason for the compiler to generate any errors if `std::is_arithmetic<T>::value` is false.

For example, your code will allow following type:

```
struct S
{
    constexpr S(bool) {}
};
```

Comment: great explanation on why it doesn't work. I think this is the most important think we can give the OP. More than the solution. +1

Answer (score 7):

(Hopefully) very soon we will be able to write it very cleanly using concepts:

```
template <class T>
concept constexpr bool Arithmetic = std::is_arithmetic_v<T>;

template <Arithmetic T, std::size_t n>
using NumericArray = std::array<T, n>;
```

And btw, this compiles and runs **now** on gcc 7 with `-fconcepts`. For gcc 6 you need to use `std::is_arithmetic<T>::value`

---

In c++14 you have some ways too.

I prefer:

```
template <class T, std::size_t n,
          class Enable = std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>>
using NumericArray = std::array<T, n>;
```

[@holyblackcat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2752075/holyblackcat) gave you another way in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39526090/2805305)

Comment: Concepts is a TS, distinct from C++17. This person who attended a Committee meeting in March said that the Concepts TS has not been voted into C++17. http://honermann.net/blog/?p=3 Has something changed since then that I've not heard about?