# template class default float parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I'm trying to define a class template that depends from a `<typename T, const double` and `std::size_t>`. I know that before C++ 14 was impossible declare a default parameter for double type in template but I read somewhere that now it's possible but I don't know how. I tried to indexing the research here and in goolge but I didn't found what I wish accomplish that is:

```
template <typename Type, double threshold = 0.5 , std::size_t Sz = 64>
class DynBmatrix 
{
   constexpr DynBmatrix(std::vector<std::vector<Type>> ) noexcept ;
}

template<typename T, double TH,std::size_t S>
class DynBmatrix<T,TH,S>
{
    if (something > TH) 
    ...
}
```

and in the main instance the template as simply

```
DynBmatrix<int> dbm{} ;
```

**EDIT** : solved as folow : thanks @Marco

```
constexpr double th = 0.5 ;

template <typename Type, const double* TH = &th , std::size_t Sz = 64>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I use float value as a template parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183087/why-cant-i-use-float-value-as-a-template-parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using : `const double* TH` instead of `double TH` and define outside the class the `constexpr double th = 0.5 ;` then you got the same behaviour