# template with special integer in the template param

Tags: c++, templates

This is a commonly seen template function

```
template <typename T>
void func(T param) {
   // ...
}
```

However, I also see templates which look like this:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>  // note the extra N
void func(T param) {
   // ...
}
```

I know this is legal, but obvious N has nothing to do with parameters' *type*. What's the official rule here on adding an extra integer in the template?  What is this called? Can I make the extra template param to be a float or double instead of integer? If not, why integer is special?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non-type template parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687540/non-type-template-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called [non-type template parameters](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters). You'r allowed to use simple types like integers

- std::nullptr_t (since C++11);
- integral type;
- lvalue reference type (to object or to function);
- pointer type (to object or to function);
- pointer to member type (to member object or to member function);
- enumeration type.

Note that since C++17 you can use `auto` to allow deduction of the non-type template parameter.

Floats and doubles are not allowed. But why?! Have a look at [Why can't I use float value as a template parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183087/why-cant-i-use-float-value-as-a-template-parameter)

Comment: Could you give some example on non-type template using lvalue reference? This is really strange that works but float doesn't. I am more curious about the *why* part...