# How do I use ratio Instead of a float?

Tags: c++, templates, floating-point, metaprogramming

So I know that I cannot use a `float` as a template parameter:

```
template<float T>
float foo(const float param) { return param + T; }
```

I've heard that [`ratio`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/ratio/ratio) can be used as an alternative. I'd like to do something like this:

```
template<ratio T>
float foo(const float param) { return param * T::num / static_cast<float>(T::den); }
```

Unfortunately `ratio` is not a complete type so that doesn't work at all. And ultimately I have to ask, why not just do:

```
template<int Num, int Denom>
float foo(const float param) { return param * Num / static_cast<float>(Denom); }
```

My preference would be to use a `ratio` because it more clearly represents what I'm trying to do. Could someone provide me a simple way to use `ratio`?

Comment: @JesperJuhl Because the standard says so, and [the compiler believes it](http://rextester.com/CBF67843)

Comment: @JesperJuhl https://stackoverflow.com/a/11518757/2642059 I mean I assume that hasn't changed? I thought that was the point of `ratio`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no type `ratio`. `std::ratio` is a class template. This template itself has numerator and denominator as template parameters.

If you want to use `std::ratio` it can be done like this:

```
template<class T>
float foo(const float param) {
    return param * T::num / static_cast<float>(T::den);
}

auto x = foo<std::ratio<4,7>>(42);
```

Comment: Haha, I even linked to `std::ratio` in the question, and still got corrected. Anyways... is there anyway that I can do an `enable_if` or similar to enforce that `T` is of type `ratio`?

Comment: You can, but why? Anything that has `num` and `den` as static members should be fine!