# Given a decimal number, find the smallest integer multiplier that gives an integer result

Tags: algorithm, math

Best to use an example to describe the problem. Lets say I have a decimal value 100.227273.

100.227273 * X = Y

I need to find the smallest positive integer X that gives integer Y.

Comment: Do you really mean decimal, or floating point?

Comment: Representation doesn't matter, at least not to me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If the 100.227273 is just an approximation and you want to get the best rational approximation, use [continued fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction).

Take 100.227273 as example.

1. Take the integer part (100) away. Now you get 100.227273 = 100 + 0.227273.
2. Invert 0.227273 to get 4.39999 (4.4?).
3. Repeat step 1 until you are satisfied with the error.

So you get

```
                       1
100.227273 = 100 + —————————
                         1
                   4 + —————
                           1
                       2 + —
                           2
```

Simplify this expression to get 2205/22.

[Editor's note: For example code, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55410253).]

Comment: +1 for continued fractions. IIRC there is a simple algorithm that uses only 3 state variables to go arbitrarily deep.

Comment: @phkahler have you perchance run into this algorithm since or recall its name/link? Would be super useful

Answer (score 12):

`1000000/gcd(1000000,227273)`. Also known as `lcm(1000000,227273)/227273`. In this case, 1 million.

What you want to do, is turn 0.227273 into a fraction in simplest form. The number you're looking for is then the denominator of that fraction. Since 227273/1000000 is already in simplest form, you're done. But if your input was 100.075, then 75/1000 is not in simplest form. The simplest form is 3/40, so the solution for X is 40.

As an optimisation, you can simplify the calculation because you know that the starting denominator is a power of 10, so its only prime factors are 2 and 5. So all you need to look for in the numerator is divisibility by 2 and 5, which is easier than Euclid's algorithm. Of course if you already have an implementation of gcd and/or lcm, then this is more effort on your part, not less.

Bear in mind when you get the result, that floating-point numbers cannot in general represent decimal fractions precisely. So once you have the mathematically correct answer, it will not *necessarily* give you an integer answer when you do a floating-point multiplication. The flip side of this is that of course the question only applies if there is a finite decimal expression of the number you're interested in.

If you have the number as a quotient in the first place, then you need to find the denominator of its simplest form directly, not by converting it to decimal and truncating it. For example, to solve this problem for the number "6 and one third", the answer is 3, not any power of 10. If the input is "the square root of 2", then there is no solution for X.

Well, actually, the smallest integer X with the property you require is `0`, but I assume you don't mean that ;-)

Comment: and OP means positive integer.

Comment: Of course. Giving the "right but wrong" answer is just my little way of pointing out the imprecision in the question.

Comment: No, -10,000,000,000 is much smaller than 0. ;)

Comment: No, it is not. It is less than 0, but it is not smaller. It's a "large negative value". Anyway, that is the only sense I've ever seen "smaller" used for the whole set of integers, by anyone who was mindful the two different possible interpretations as they were saying it ;-). If you want the minimum value of a set of integers, say "least", not "smallest".

Comment: Should I edit the question? I didn't really think about all the mathematical details (also, English is my second language).

Comment: @Davorin: you could change "smallest possible integer" to "smallest positive integer", but don't worry about it. Despite the last line of my answer, I think the question was fine: everybody understood it. For positive integers, "least" and "smallest" are the same thing, and in the context of the question I think it is obvious that's what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

I've got a feeling you actually mean this:
[How to convert floats to human-readable fractions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95727/how-to-convert-floats-to-human-readable-fractions)

Comment: After some examination I think this is exactly what I'll use :)

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that the input decimal `r` is a positive rational number `r` with a terminating decimal representation.

Let `d` be the number of digits after the decimal point (assume that we have trimmed all extraneous zeros from the decmial representation of `r`). Then note that `10^d * r` is an integer `m`. Let `g = gcd(10^d, m)`. Then `10^d / g * r = m / g` is an integer `p`. Let `q = 10^d / g`. I claim that `q` is the smallest such positive integer.

Answer (score 1):

If your positive decimal value D has n digits to the right of the decimal point, then D * 10^n is an integer and X = 10^n / gcf(10^n, D * 10^n) = lcm(10^n, D * 10^n) is the smallest positive integer X.

Comment: Except that it looks like he doesn't know how many digits long the fractional part is beforehand.