# how to calculate absolute values , first/second degree equations, derivative and integration using DDMathParser

Tags: objective-c, ddmathparser

i am developing a calculator for iPad . I would like to ask you if there is a way for DDMathParser to calculate absolute values , e.g (2+4*5)/88 should give 1/4 and not 0.25 .  Is it possible to have two modes absolute and exact(decimal)? I would also like to ask you if there is a way to calculate first and second degree equations e.g : 2*x+3=5-7*x should give the value of x=... , derivatives and integrations using DDMathParser? 
I would really appreciate any help. Thank you in advance . Best regards

Comment: That's not what absolute value is.

Comment: ok, then how should i call this ? Do you have any ideas on how to implement this using DDMathParser? Thank you in advance

Comment: Probably a [fractional value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552537/convert-decimal-to-fraction-in-objective-c), and what you're trying to do with the derivatives and integrals is a tremendously complicated task. There is no build in way to do this with DDMathParser.

Comment: thank you very much. Do you have any idea about latex functions? Is there a possibility that the DDMathParser can calculate them? Thank you in advance