# Getting numerator and denominator without using numden() in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Is there anyway of obtaining the numerator and denominator in MATLAB without using numden() function? For example:
`format rational
x=5/2;`

I want to obtain 5 as num and 2 as den. Can you help me with this tricky problem.

Comment: Look at another so [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95727/how-to-convert-floats-to-human-readable-fractions)

Comment: Why you do not want to use numdem? It would be much simpler, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
[N,D] = rat(2.5)
```

Otherwise, if you insist on doing it yourself, you can do something like

```
N = 2.5;

D=1; while (int64(N)~=N), N=N*10; D=D*10; end

g = gcd(N,D);

D = D/g;
N = N/g;
```