# PHP - Simple Math, Hard Coding. 0.000126% into fraction of 1/10000 etc

Tags: php, math

I need to turn small percentages into large fractions. If I have a percentage of **0.000126%** - I would like to put this into a fraction of something like *1/10,000* - etc. How, do I turn a small percentage into a fraction that is not the lowest common fraction.

The answer to the equation is simple.

```
0.000126% = 0.00126/10% = 0.0126/100% = 0.126/1000% = ... = 126/1000000%
```

Then find common factors. 2 goes into each, so that's the same as *63/500000*. That's as simple as I can make it.

Thus, in code - how do I get this damn fraction. Grrrr.... frustrating o.O! Several attempts - and I'm failing at each. Any ideas?

Comment: Cnotinuous fractions theory should help you. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95727/how-to-convert-floats-to-human-readable-fractions

Comment: You're going to have a bad time. Php cannot accurately store `0.000126`, just like you cannot represent 1/3 in decimal.

Comment: @Eric: PHP may not have out of the box fraction support but the OP is trying to do just that. Floats cannot accurately store many numbers but fractions can. It's not hard at all.

Comment: Then the OP will need to parse fractions from a string. If you try to get an exact fractional representation of a float, then you've lost. A better goal might be "find the closest fraction with a denominator below 1000"

Comment: essentially, you could write a function such that `fractionify("0.000126") == array(63, 500000)`, but you wouldn't be able to make `fractionify(0.000126) == array(63, 500000)`

Comment: I've turned binomial coefficients and permutations of trillions, into easy to read percentages that PHP can interpret using every method I could derive at. Now I'm trying to turn the small percentiles, into a fraction that is readable. I understand what you're referring to, Eric. But I refuse to stand at a wall, lol. I don't care if it's ridiculously hard - I just need a direction to go, and I'll get to my answer. The continuous fraction theory which @ypercube has led me to - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95727/how-to-convert-floats-to-human-readable-fractions - is a good start.

Comment: Thank you for the input guys :) I'm further than I was an hour ago, lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a PHP function that uses continued fractions to find a rational approximation to a given (positive) floating point number with a relative error less than a given tolerance.

```
<?php
function float2frac($n, $tolerance = 1.e-6) {
    $h1=1; $h2=0;
    $k1=0; $k2=1;
    $b = $n;
    do {
        $a = floor($b);
        $aux = $h1; $h1 = $a*$h1+$h2; $h2 = $aux;
        $aux = $k1; $k1 = $a*$k1+$k2; $k2 = $aux;
        $b = 1/($b-$a);
    } while (abs($n-$h1/$k1) > $n*$tolerance);

    return "$h1/$k1";
}

printf("%s\n", float2rat(66.66667)); # 200/3
printf("%s\n", float2rat(sqrt(2)));  # 1393/985
```

I have written more about this algorithm and why it works, and even a JavaScript demo here: http://jonisalonen.com/2012/converting-decimal-numbers-to-ratios/

Comment: Well done, @Joni - thank you. That's brilliant work.