# objective-c convert from float to NSString representation

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a float number that I would like to display in a string way.

E.g.

0.33 should be displayed as 1/3

0.5 should be displayed as 1/2

How can I do it in objective-c with no switch? (as I could have 3/4, 2/5 etc)

Comment: What do you mean by "no switch"?  Also `0.33` isn't `1/3` is it...

Comment: Converting decimals to fractions and back again sounds like something you might have learned in grade school ;-) Just remember to simplify your fraction http://www.mathsisfun.com/simplifying-fractions.html

Comment: This maybe help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95727/how-to-convert-floats-to-human-readable-fractions

Comment: no switch - I mean using a switch case statement to find it

Comment: @JasonWhitehorn the question is how to "read" it in objective-c!

Answer (score 1):

There's no objective-c way to do this, you'll have to implemente it yourself and find an algorightm.

What about trying combinations of A/B  where A,B from 0 to 10, until you reach the number?

Comment: Using "Continued Fractions", as in the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95727/how-to-convert-floats-to-human-readable-fractions (link given by Javi above), is *much* faster than trying all combinations.

Comment: Thanks do you know if there is a library for it in objective-c?