# Conversion a float-pointing types to a fraction

Tags: c++

I have some float-pointing number (I don't know float is it, double or long double), and I want to convert It to the fraction. I look at the `frexp` function, and I get mantissa and exponent of float-pointing type (FPT) number. I look at the `struct numbers_limits<float, double or long double>`, and I get this fields: `radix` (2), `digits` (as I know, it is in the base **radix**), `digits10`, `max_digits10`. I think to conversion I must use `max_digits10`, but I don't sure, and unfortunately my known of English do not let me understand which of this fields I must use to most accurate conversion. As I know, mantissa always have limited sum of bits, but in decimal base it is unlimited decimal fraction. **Anyway**, how many digits in **decimal** representation of mantissa I must use to most accurate conversion from FPT to fraction?

Or maybe I must find in mantissa a period, and convert it to fraction as a periodic decimal number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting answers because you are headed the wrong way here. Presumably you are trying to find a rational representation in base 10, but floats are not stored base 10. So forget about the mantissa ans exponent thing. Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95727/how-to-convert-floats-to-human-readable-fractions) to an answer to your question. Good luck!