# how to convert a float to a fraction in python?

Tags: python, class

I am trying to define a class Fraction:

```
 def __init__(self,num=0,denom=1):
        self.num = num
        self.denom = denom
```

And I also want to define a **add** method,

```
def __add__(self,right):

    if type(right) is int:
        return (self.num/self.denom) + right
    if type(right) is Fraction:
        return ((self.num/self.denom)+(right.num/right.denom))


def __radd__(self,left):
    return (self.num/self.denom)+left
```

It works, and always returns a float. However, I want it to return a fraction.
For example:
if I test:

```
f = Frac(1,2)
f + Frac(1,3) 
f + 2 
Frac(1,3) + f
2 + f
```

I always get:

```
*Error: f+Frac(1,3) -> 0.8333333333333333 but should -> 5/6
*Error: f+2 -> 2.5 but should -> 5/2
*Error: Frac(1,3)+f -> 0.8333333333333333 but should -> 5/6
*Error: 2+f -> 2.5 but should -> 5/2
```

Are there any methods that can convert the result from a float to a fraction?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Is it what you are looking for?  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95727/how-to-convert-floats-to-human-readable-fractions

Comment: Is your intention that the `__add__` and `__radd__` special methods return instances of your `Frac` type? Because right now they don't.

Comment: Are you aware that Python has a [`fractions` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html)?

Comment: I know, but I just want to define a new class called Fraction.

Comment: Ok. There's nothing wrong with reinventing the wheel if the point is to learn how to make wheels.

Comment: ...Well I just want to do some exercise about building a class. Thanks for your attention anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't create a float in the first place. For example,

```
def __add__(self,right):

    if type(right) is int:
        return Fraction(self.num + right*self.denom, self.denom)
    elif if type(right) is Fraction:
        # Reducing the answer to lowest terms is left
        # as an exercise for the reader
        return Fraction(self.num*right.denom + right.num*self.denom,
                        self.denom*right.denom)
```

Comment: How about the __radd__ method?

Comment: Apply the same logic shown above in `__add__`.

Answer (score 0):

The Python documentation section on [Emulating numeric types](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) explains how to implement your own numeric type.

The [`numbers` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/numbers.html) in the standard library also contains an abstract base class for rational types (like your fraction type).

And of course there is also an existing implementation in the standard library that does exactly what you intend: [`fractions.Fraction`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html). You can [read its source code in `Lib/fractions.py`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/fractions.py) if you're interested in learning how it works.

Answer (score 0):

The fraction module of Python may help you:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html

Example:

```
from fractions import Fraction
Fraction('3.1415926535897932').limit_denominator(1000)
```

Solution: Fraction(355, 113)