# Precision issues when converting a decimal number to its rational equivalent

Tags: c++, c, double, rational-number

I have problem of converting a double (say **N**) to p/q form (rational form), for this I have the following strategy :

1. Multiply double N by a large number say $k = 10^{10}$
2. then `p = y*k` and `q = k`
3. Take `gcd(p,q)` and find `p = p/gcd(p,q)` and `q = p/gcd(p,q)`

when `N = 8.2` , Answer is correct if we solve using pen and paper,  but as `8.2` is represented as `8.19999999` in `N` (double), it causes problem in its rational form conversion.

I tried it doing other way as : (I used a large no. 10^k instead of 100)

`if(abs(y*100 - round(y*100)) < 0.000001) y = round(y*100)/100`

But this approach also doesn't give right representation all the time.

Is there any way I could carry out the equivalent conversion from double to p/q ?

Comment: Not a answer but you can take reference of python Decimal and Fraction module and see their implementation

Comment: import fractions 
import decimal

fractions.Fraction(decimal.Decimal('0.5'))  =>Fraction(1, 2) . (This is python result )

Comment: `double`s  are just approximations of some real values. Arithmetic can't be accurate. Revise your strategy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert floats to human-readable fractions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95727/how-to-convert-floats-to-human-readable-fractions)

Comment: FWIW, a `double` is exactly equal to the fraction `2^exponent * (2^53 + mantissa) / 2^53`.

Comment: It's easy (but also hard), the binary floating point mantissa is a series of rational fractions (1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16 etc)  so all you have to do is sum the fractions and you will have an exact rational fraction for the binary floating point number.  I know this is not what you want - that's the hard part.

Comment: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Convert_decimal_number_to_rational#C

Comment: For what numbers does your current code fail?

Comment: There's no problem in converting 8.2 because this value doesn't exist in the set of machine floating point numbers. No value, no problem. Perhaps you have a problem with the non-existence of 8.2? Well it sucks. But we can't make 8.2 appear out of nowhere. So if you need exactly 8.2, don't use doubles.

Answer (score 1):

Floating point arithmetic is very difficult. As has been mentioned in the comments, part of the difficulty is that you need to represent your numbers in binary.

For example, the number 0.125 can be represented exactly in binary:

```
0.125 = 2^-3 = 0b0.001
```

But the number 0.12 cannot.

To 11 significant figures:

```
0.12 = 0b0.00011110101
```

If this is converted back to a decimal then the error becomes obvious:

```
0b0.00011110101 = 0.11962890625
```

So if you write:

```
double a = 0.2;
```

What the machine actually does is find the closest binary representation of 0.2 that it can hold within a double data type. This is an approximation since as we saw above, 0.2 cannot be exactly represented in binary.

One possible approach is to define an 'epsilon' which determines how close your number can be to the nearest representable binary floating point.

Here is a good article on floating points:

https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/

Comment: The OP already knows that one can't exactly represent 8.2.  What he/she is asking is how to obtain 41/5 (presumably), despite this limitation.

Comment: From the OP's comments it wasn't clear if they understood why 8.2 cannot be exactly represented in binary. In this answer I explain why and then go on to suggest the epsilon method, which is one way to obtain rational answers despite the limitation of floating point machine representation.

Answer (score 1):

> have problem of converting a double (say **N**) to p/q form
>    ... when N = 8.2

A typical `double` cannot encode 8.2 *exactly*.  Instead the closest representable `double` is about

```
8.19999999999999928945726423989981412887573...
8.20000000000000106581410364015027880668640...  // next closest
```

When code does

```
double N = 8.2;
```

It will be the `8.19999999999999928945726423989981412887573...` that is converted into rational form.

---

## Converting a `double` to p/q form:

> Multiply double N by a large number say $k = 10^{10}$

This may overflow the `double`.  First step should be to determine if the `double` is large, it which case, it is a whole number.

Do not multiple by some power of 10 as `double` certainly uses a binary encoding.  Multiplication by 10, 100, etc. may introduce round-off error.

---

C implementations of `double` overwhelmingly use a binary encoding, so that `FLT_RADIX == 2`.

Then every finite `double x` has a significand that is a fraction of some integer over some power of 2: a binary fraction of `DBL_MANT_DIG` digits  [@Richard Critten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48730844/precision-issues-when-converting-a-decimal-number-to-its-rational-equivalent/48732712#comment84461030_48730844).  This is often 53 binary digits.

Determine the exponent of the `double`.  If large enough or `x == 0.0`, the `double` is a whole number.

Otherwise, scale a numerator and denominator by `DBL_MANT_DIG`.  While the numerator is even, halve both the numerator and denominator.  As the `denominator` is a power-of-2, no other prime values are needed for simplification consideration.

```
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void form_ratio(double x) {
  double numerator = x;
  double denominator = 1.0;
  if (isfinite(numerator) && x != 0.0) {
    int expo;
    frexp(numerator, &expo);
    if (expo < DBL_MANT_DIG) {
      expo = DBL_MANT_DIG - expo;
      numerator = ldexp(numerator, expo);
      denominator = ldexp(1.0, expo);
      while (fmod(numerator, 2.0) == 0.0 && denominator > 1.0) {
        numerator /= 2.0;
        denominator /= 2.0;
      }
    }
  }
  int pre = DBL_DECIMAL_DIG;
  printf("%.*g --> %.*g/%.*g\n", pre, x, pre, numerator, pre, denominator);
}

int main(void) {
  form_ratio(123456789012.0);
  form_ratio(42.0);
  form_ratio(1.0 / 7);
  form_ratio(867.5309);
}
```

Output

```
123456789012 --> 123456789012/1
42 --> 42/1
0.14285714285714285 --> 2573485501354569/18014398509481984
867.53089999999997 --> 3815441248019913/4398046511104
```