# Expressing Radians C++

Tags: c++, angle, degrees, radians

How would I convert degrees to radians **exactly**. Rather than showing `0.785398` I want the program to show `pi/4`.

I am currently using this script to convert degrees into radians.

`cout << angle * M_PI / 180.0 << " radians";`

Comment: `exactly` -  invent a computer that can store floating numbers exactly. If you want to show _a string_ `"pi/4"` rather then the actual floating point value, you have to implement a library that will do just that.

Comment: @KamilCuk You can implement that without needing fancy architecture. For example a `rational` type that stores a numerator and a denumerator, maybe with a bigint library can pretty much do this. No need to invent a new type of computer. Though some *operations* are necessarily approximations, but you can still store those approximations as exact rational values. Maybe a bit trickier if you want to account for irrational values like pi, but can absolutely done in software.

Comment: convert `angle / 180.0` to a proper fraction and then stick pi in the numerator.

Comment: Why the negative votes?

Answer (score 1):

You might do

```
 std::cout << angle / 180.0 << " pi radians";
```

Which will print

```
 0.25 pi radians
```

You might be interested by [how-to-convert-floats-to-human-readable-fractions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95727/how-to-convert-floats-to-human-readable-fractions) to convert `0.25` into `1/4`.