# Detecting unit differences in data (SAS)

Tags: sas, difference, data-quality

I have two sets of financial data that tend to contain differences due to unit errors e.g. $10000 in one dataset may be $1000 in the other.

I'm trying to code a check for such differences, but the only way I can think of is to divide the two variables and see if the difference is in a table of 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 10, 100 etc, but it would be hard to catch all of the differences.

Is there a smarter way to do this?

Comment: So you want to classify a difference between 10,000 and 1,000 as another type of change than  when the difference is jsut a change in value? Like between 10,000 and 9,500?

Comment: Is it possible to go back to your original source data and see if there's a way to read the units from the table somehow. Usually in the axis or variable label somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Use `proc compare`. Be sure the two datasets are sorted in identical order, either by row or by specific groups. Use the `by` statement as needed. More info on options can be found in the [documentation](https://go.documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=proc&docsetTarget=p1l5iwaf47ma83n1euxxp10g8xh5.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en).

Example - compare a modified `cars` dataset with `sashelp.cars`:

```
data cars_modified;
    set sashelp.cars;

    if(mod(_N_, 2) = 0) then msrp = msrp - 100;
run;

proc compare base    = sashelp.cars 
             compare = cars_modified 
             out     = out_differences 
             outnoequal 
             outdif
             noprint;
    var msrp;
run;
```

Only the observations with differences are output in `out_differences`:

```
_TYPE_  _OBS_   MSRP
DIF     2      $-100
DIF     4      $-100
DIF     6      $-100
DIF     8      $-100
DIF     10     $-100
...
```

Answer (score 0):

So you appear to be asking to find cases where X/Y is a number that is exactly 1.00Exx where XX is an integer, other than 0.

```
data _null_;
do x=1,10,100,1000;
  do y=1,2,3,10.1,10 ;
   ratio = x/y;
   power = floor(log10(ratio));
   if power ne 0 and 1.00 = round(ratio/10**power,0.01) then 
     put 'Ratio of ' x 'over ' y 'is 10**' power '.' 
   ;    
  end;
end;
run;
```

Results:

```
Ratio of 1 over 10 is 10**-1 .
Ratio of 10 over 1 is 10**1 .
Ratio of 100 over 1 is 10**2 .
Ratio of 100 over 10 is 10**1 .
Ratio of 1000 over 1 is 10**3 .
Ratio of 1000 over 10 is 10**2 .
```

Answer (score 0):

For a numeric value **X** you can compute the nearest the rational expression, **p/q**.

If you calculate ratio

```
X = amount_for_source_A / amount_from_source_B;
status = math.rational(X,1e5,p,q);
```

the ratio will be a multiple of 10 if `p=1 or q=1`

Example:

```
proc ds2;
  package math / overwrite = yes;
    method rational(double x, double maxden, in_out integer p, in_out integer q) returns double;
      /*
      ** FROM: https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/numth/frap.c
      ** FROM: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95727/how-to-convert-floats-to-human-readable-fractions
      **
      ** find rational approximation to given real number
      ** David Eppstein / UC Irvine / 8 Aug 1993
      **
      ** With corrections from Arno Formella, May 2008
      **
      ** Modified for Proc DS2, Richard DeVenezia, Jan 2020.
      **
      ** usage: rational(r,d,p,q)
      **   x is real number to approx
      **   maxden is the maximum denominator allowed
      **   p is return for numerator
      **   q is return for denominator
      **   returns 0 if no problems
      **
      ** based on the theory of continued fractions
      ** if x = a1 + 1/(a2 + 1/(a3 + 1/(a4 + ...)))
      ** then best approximation is found by truncating this series
      ** (with some adjustments in the last term).
      **
      ** Note the fraction can be recovered as the first column of the matrix
      **  ( a1 1 ) ( a2 1 ) ( a3 1 ) ...
      **  ( 1  0 ) ( 1  0 ) ( 1  0 )
      ** Instead of keeping the sequence of continued fraction terms,
      ** we just keep the last partial product of these matrices.
      */

      declare integer m[0:1,0:1];
      declare double startx e1 e2;
      declare integer ai t result p1 q1 p2 q2;

      startx = x;

      /* initialize matrix */
      m[0,0] = 1; m[1,1] = 1;
      m[0,1] = 0; m[1,0] = 0;

      /* loop finding terms until denom gets too big */
      do while (1);

        ai = x;

        if not ( m[1,0] * ai + m[1,1] < maxden ) then leave;

        t = m[0,0] * ai + m[0,1];
        m[0,1] = m[0,0];
        m[0,0] = t;

        t = m[1,0] * ai + m[1,1];
        m[1,1] = m[1,0];
        m[1,0] = t;

        if x = ai then leave;     %* AF: division by zero;

        x = 1 / (x - ai);

        if x > 2147483647 /*x'7FFFFFFF'*/ then leave;  %* AF: representation failure;
      end;

      /* now remaining x is between 0 and 1/ai */
      /* approx as either 0 or 1/m where m is max that will fit in maxden */
      /* first try zero */

      p1 = m[0,0];
      q1 = m[1,0];
      e1 = startx - 1.0 * p1 / q1;

      /* now try other possibility */

      ai = (maxden - m[1,1]) / m[1,0];

      m[0,0] = m[0,0] * ai + m[0,1];
      m[1,0] = m[1,0] * ai + m[1,1];

      p2 = m[0,0];
      q2 = m[1,0];
      e2 = startx - 1.0 * p2 / q2;

      if abs(e1) <= abs(e2) then do;
        p = p1;
        q = q1;
      end;
      else do;
        p = p2;
        q = q2;
      end;

      return 0;
    end;
  endpackage;
run;
quit;
```

`* Example uage;`

```
proc ds2;
  data _null_;
    declare package math math();
    declare double x;
    declare int p1 q1 p q;

    method run();
      streaminit(12345);

      x = 0;
      do _n_ = 1 to 20;
        p1 = ceil(rand('uniform',9));
        q1 = ceil(rand('uniform',9));

        x + 1. * p1 / q1;

        math.rational (x, 10000, p, q);

        put 'add' p1 '/' q1 '  ' x=best16. 'is' p '/' q;
      end;
    end;
  enddata;
run;
quit;
```

```
----- LOG -----
add 4 / 1    x=               4 is 4 / 1
add 4 / 2    x=               6 is 6 / 1
add 2 / 7    x=6.28571428571429 is 44 / 7
add 4 / 6    x=6.95238095238095 is 146 / 21
add 5 / 2    x=9.45238095238095 is 397 / 42
add 5 / 2    x= 11.952380952381 is 251 / 21
add 7 / 1    x= 18.952380952381 is 398 / 21
add 8 / 6    x=20.2857142857143 is 142 / 7
add 9 / 3    x=23.2857142857143 is 163 / 7
add 8 / 2    x=27.2857142857143 is 191 / 7
add 3 / 1    x=30.2857142857143 is 212 / 7
add 9 / 3    x=33.2857142857143 is 233 / 7
add 4 / 3    x=34.6190476190476 is 727 / 21
add 4 / 6    x=35.2857142857143 is 247 / 7
add 1 / 9    x=35.3968253968254 is 2230 / 63
add 8 / 3    x=38.0634920634921 is 2398 / 63
add 2 / 4    x=38.5634920634921 is 4859 / 126
add 5 / 1    x=43.5634920634921 is 5489 / 126
add 1 / 2    x=44.0634920634921 is 2776 / 63
add 2 / 7    x=44.3492063492064 is 2794 / 63
```

[DS2 math package](https://www.devenezia.com/downloads/sas/samples/#mathpackage)