# Is it possible to sort array with some "between" numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Is it possible, somehow, to sort array with some "between" numbers?

```
[31, 33/34, 34, 29].sort((a, b) => a.toString().localeCompare(b.toString()))
```

*//to return  **[29, 31, 33/34, 34]**
instead **[0.9705882352, 29, 31, 34]***

Comment: you need strings as data.

Comment: I was wondering if converting the decimal representation to fraction would help here, but 0.5 can be transformed to multiple ranges, say 1/2 or 50/100.

Comment: Strings data - I know, but the challenge is - if it's possible with numbers (and exact number format 33/34)

Comment: That is impossible since that is `0.9705882352`. We have no clue what was used to get that number. If you want this to work, you need to use strings as the first comment said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the only way this will work is if you use string to capture the numbers. The engine is going to store your `33/34` as the decimal. There is no way to get the original value back.

Doing it is just a simple parse and sort.

```js
var nums = ['31', '33/34', '34', '29']

nums.sort((a, b) => Number(a.split('/')[0]) - Number(b.split('/')[0]));

console.log(nums);
```

Now you may need to add more logic if you can have multiple numbers to push the 33/34 to the right spot. Not knowing all of the use cases, I am going to not try to guess.

Comment: *"There is no way to get the original value back."* That statement is a bit too absolute. See for instance this related question: [How to convert floats to human-readable fractions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95727/how-to-convert-floats-to-human-readable-fractions) ([and this javascript answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/681534/1934901)) or [Wikipedia: Continued fraction # Best rational approximations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Best_rational_approximations)

Comment: @Stef You can not guarantee it was a reduced value. If you can guarantee it, then maybe there is a chance you can process it like crazy to get it. OR you just store the data correctly to start and there is nothing to do.

Answer (score 0):

When converting to string your are converting the fraction 33/34 (=`0.9705882352`). That's all that's visible the JS interpreter: it does not matter whether you provided `0.9705882352` or `33/34` or `66/68`. So as indicated by @ninascholz & @epascarello, you have to start off with strings. With strings, your code should work fine as in the demo below:

```js
const nums = ['31', '33/34', '34', '29']

nums.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b));

console.log( nums );
```